# How do i add starttime (H,M,S) to startdate

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker, fullcalendar

I would like to have a separate field where i can add the time in the database in the same cell as the date.

everything works but the time doesnt change in the database. How can i fix this?:

agenda.html:

```
<!---------------------------------------------------------
<! HTML/PHP
<!----------------------------------------------------------->
<title>Blackboks &bull; Agenda</title>
<div id="header">
        <div class="header-text">Agenda</div>
        <body class="modal-header">
<button id="b1" class="btn btn-primary "><i class="fa fa-plus-square">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Nieuwe afspraak</button>
<form class="form-inline">
<div id="d1" title="Nieuwe afspraak" style="display: none">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Title:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Titel" id="name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Beschrijving:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="userdesc" placeholder="Beschrijving" id="desc"/>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Starttijd:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="userstart" placeholder="Starttijd" id="start"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Eindtijd:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="userend" placeholder="Eindtijd" id="end"/>
            </div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="d2" title="Checking Empty..." style="display:none;">
    <p>Vul alstublieft wat in....!</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="table-row">
<!-- <div class="header_title" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Agenda</div> -->
 <div class="agenda">
<html>
<head>
<link href='<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/js/fullcalendarextern.js'></script>
<script src='<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/js/nieuweafspraak.js'></script>
<link href="<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/assets/css/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>

 body {
  margin-top: 40px;

  }


 #calendar {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
</div>
</div>
```

nieuwe afspraak.js:

```
    $(function () {
    // Dialog Open   
    $("#d1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape:true, 
    resizable:false, 
    show:'fade',
    buttons: { 
      "Add": function() { 

        var id = $("#id").val(),
        name = $('#name').val(),
        desc = $('#desc').val(),
        age = $('#age').val(),
        end = $('#end').val();

        if(id=='' || name=='' || desc=='' || age=='' || end=='')
            {
                //alert("Please do not empty....!",title="Hello");
                $("#d2").dialog("open");
                $("#d2").dialog({
                    buttons:{
                        "OK":function(){
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                $("#id:first").focus(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                exit;
            }//End if statement

        $.post('../testcalendar/db/process.php',{
            user_id: id, user_name: name, user_desc: desc, user_age: age, user_end: end, action:'joined'
        }); var nTime = 1 * 50;
                window.setTimeout("location.reload()", nTime);//End Post
        $("#id").val('');
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#desc").val('');
        $("#age").val('');  
        $("#end").val('');      
        $(this).dialog("close");        
        },
      "Cancel": function() { 
        $("#id").val('');
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#desc").val('');
        $("#age").val('');
        $("#end").val('');
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    }
});


$("#d2").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape:true, 
    resizable:false, 
    show:'fade',
    buttons: { 
      "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } 
    }
    });

$("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#d1").dialog("open");
});
$("#age").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$("#end").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

});
```

process.php:

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include 'connection.php';
function user_joined($user_name,$user_desc, $user_start,$user_starttime $user_end){
        $q = "INSERT INTO evenement (title,description,start,end) VALUES 
            ('".$user_name."','".$user_desc."','".$user_start.$user_starttime."','".$user_end."')";
    mysql_query($q);
    }

if(isset($_POST['user_name'],$_POST['user_desc'],$_POST['user_start','user_starttime'],$_POST['user_end'],$_POST['action'])){
        $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
        $user_desc=$_POST['user_desc'];
        $user_start=$_POST['user_start','user_starttime'];
        $user_end=$_POST['user_end'];
        $action=$_POST['action'];
        if ($action=='joined'){
            user_joined($user_name, $user_desc, $user_start, $user_starttime, $user_end);
            }
    }
/*if ( (isset($_POST["id"]) && strlen($_POST["id"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["id"]) <= 60) &&
    (isset($_POST["name"]) && strlen($_POST["name"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["name"]) <= 50) &&
    (isset($_POST["age"]) && strlen($_POST["age"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["age"]) <= 40) ) 
{   //check $_POST["name"] and $_POST["address"] and $_POST["city"] are not empty

    $id   = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age   = $_POST["age"];

    $q = "INSERT INTO tbltest ( id, name, age) VALUES 
            ('".$id."','".$name."','".$age."')";
    mysql_query($q); 

}*/

?>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost"; 
// Place the username for the MySQL database here 
$db_username = "root";  
// Place the password for the MySQL database here 
$db_pass = "root";  
// Place the name for the MySQL database here 
$db_name = "calendar"; 

// Run the actual connection here  
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");
```

?>

Comment: Well.. you have an error in your PHP : `user_joined($user_name,$user_desc, $user_start,$user_starttime $user_end)` should be `user_joined($user_name,$user_desc, $user_start,$user_starttime, $user_end)`

Comment: `$user_start=$_POST['user_start','user_starttime'];` is also invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can pass an array like that in you db script.
If i've well understand you want to concat date and time , so try this :

```
 $user_start=$_POST['user_start']." ".$_POST['user_starttime'];
```